# What is this hairy weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

I consider this plant weed. But what is it? Zone 7.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your photos are pretty, but a bit blurry - I can’t clearly see the hairs. To differentiate Urticas, seeing whether it has trichomes (stinging hairs) or not would help, also a leaf that’s fully visible to gauge the width:length ratio and perhaps a photo of the whole plant. And as I said before: where in the world is this growing?

Answer (score 2):

This is a stinging nettle (*[Urtica dioica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica)*), it stings as hell so be careful not to touch it with bare hands.

You can also make tea from it.

Comment: It doesnt sting at all

Comment: The leaves are gentle while touching

Comment: How about that you made a wrong guess?

Comment: Looks like a stinging nettle to me

Comment: Stinging nettles generally won't sting you on the pads of your fingers and palms of hands.

Comment: dry it and eat the leaves, very nutritious

Comment: To test the sting, you need to wipe the underside of the leaves, tip to stem with some soft skin - adults’ fingers can be too calloused. The other direction usually won’t sting. Also, gripping the plant very firmly can cause the trichomes to break off instead of penetrate your skin. But a magnifying lens is the better (and less painful) method to check for stinging hairs.

Answer (score 0):

If a plant looks like a stinging nettle ([Urtica dioica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica)), but doesn’t sting, it’s probably the (rarer) fen or stingless nettle ([Urtica dioica subsp. galeopsifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica_subsp._galeopsifolia) - or a crossbreed, which can exhibit traits from both parents to varying degrees, e.g. have fewer stinging hairs. A safe id needs a microscope and chromosome count, though.

[Wildflowerfinder.org.uk](http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/N/Nettle(Fen)/Nettle(Fen).htm) has useful photos comparing both.